# Mounting TV on Plywood over Window

Tags: mounting, plywood

[image]

I need to mount a TV over my window. It is a 70" TV and weighs 96 lbs. I was thinking of using the framing of the window, there are 2 studs that are 54" apart. I included a diagram of my idea but I am not sure if this idea is going to work. I was thinking of filling the gap between the windows with some wood and drill the plywood over that onto the 2 studs. Then drill the TV Mount onto the plywood.

Are the studs too far apart with no support in the middle? Is this idea feasible? If so, how thick does the plywood need to be? What kind of hardware do I need, lag bolts, screws, etc...? How many do I need to drill into each stud? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you given consideration to the glare you are going to get from the windows while using the TV? Unless this area is darkened with light blocking shades, you are going to have problems seeing the screen in the daytime because of the light emitting from the windows. Just a thought.

Comment: Yes, the TV is currently in front of the window on a stand. So I get no glare issues at all. No direct sunlight goes through this window. Thanks though for the tip.

Comment: If your window is just like the one in the photo than what you have labeled as studs are not likely studs but part of the window frame.

Answer (score 3):

You do not want to cover over the window with a TV. First of all there is the glare point that  Paulster2 points out. That alone should make you take stock of this situation and see what a bad idea this is. However there are a number of additional considerations as well.

1. Windows have a role of safety exit possibility if you ever get caught trapped in a room during a fire. This for both outbound escape and for inbound access by emergency personnel.
2. There is a reason windows are added to a house. Obviously it is to allow light in so that the room does not look like a cave.

If you have no usable wall space to mount the TV then get your self a console table. These do not have to be that expensive and you can even get them with an integrated post assembly that permits mounting the TV bracket with tilt and swivel capability. Best with this approach is you can move it around if your change your TV room layout or go off to a different house.

Talking about moving. Say you did move after you had mounted a TV over a window. Think of the mess in the window trim that would need repairing before you could sell.

Lastly, putting a TV over a window is just weird.

Comment: +1 I like your answer better than mine. But just in case he does not listen ...

Comment: It's possible that because there are *so many* windows in the room this is the only option. In which case light/egress might not be that big of a deal.

Comment: @Brad - If there are that many windows then the use of a posted console table is even more appropriate. Putting TVs and plywood across windows is weird and may even make the house look like a boarded up unit from the outside.

Comment: I get that this sounds weird but my living room is weird. I have only 2 walls that I could possibly put this on. One is a very large fireplace, the TV would be way to high to mount above the fireplace. The other option is my proposed idea. I have also moved my TV all over the room and everywhere I put it, it's awkward. This makes the rest of the furniture placed awkwardly too.

Comment: Currently I already have the TV on a stand in front of this window. The set up I have now makes the whole room look better. The mounting idea would just make this set up look cleaner. Instead of seeing the back of the TV you will see a white board with a picture on it instead of the back of the TV with a bunch of wires. It also saves space. I already have 9 windows in this room so I am okay with sacrificing light coming through this one window which we rarely every use. Also this window does not open.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the plywood. The weight of the TV (and don't forget the weight of the mounting bracket) is not that large. Books on shelves routinely weigh much more than that. And most of the pressure is downward. You probably could get away with 1/2 inch board, but I would probably go to with 3/4 to reduce bowing.

Your proposed frame for the plywood seems very wide without middle support. I would add horizontal members across the top and bottom that extend over the vertical window frame members, and an upright in the middle. Your illustrated uprights, as well as my suggested middle brace, could fit between the upper and lower horizontal supports.

I would attach the plywood to the frame with numerous wood screws, probably #10 or 12, about 2" long. I would space them no more than 8" apart. I would attach the plywood/frame structure to the window framing with lag bolts, through both the plywood and your new framing. I would use at least four lag bolts on each side, probably 5/16 or 3/8, long enough to reach 2" into the studs behind the window fascia boards. All screw holes should be predrilled.

I think the best approach to mounting the bracket would be to use bolts and nuts with large fender washers through holes drilled in the plywood. Probably 1/4" bolts.

You can do this. But, as Paulster2 suggests, you need to consider whether you *should*.

Comment: You can see my other replies on why I'm doing this. Thank you for your informative answer. I've talked to a few people and they added some suggestions that were closer to my diagram but what you suggested is probably more safer which were my concerns in the first place. I will have to think about this a little more. I worry that building a frame behind the plywood would make it stick out way too much for this to be feasible. So you think the plywood drilled to the studs and sitting on the sill is not strong enough to hold?

Comment: It might be fine. But a large plywood sheet with no support in the middle has a significant chance of bowing, even if it is 3/4. Adding 100+ ponds pulling outward increases that risk.

Answer (score 0):

just add two 2x4 in the middle that is what i did there is no glare since the window is behind the tv